# grep -oPz (GNU grep 3.1) does not match \n after positive lookahead

Tags: regex, bash, perl, grep, gnu

As a simplified example I have `printf "abc\ndef\nghi\n" | grep -oPz '\w{2}(?=c|f|i)\n'` and that does not match anything, however `grep -oPz '\w{2}(?=(c|f|i)\n)'` does. Why is that? I need the newline in the output.

Desired output is to match the rows and output them without the lookahead part eg. `ab\n`

Comment: The lookahead says that the next character should be a c, f, or i (Should be using `[cfi]` for that, btw), but then you try to match a newline as the next character. Both parts cannot both match.

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: @Cyrus Done. Basically I want to output first part of a row, then nothing from the second part and then newline (does not matter what the concrete regexes are).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ab` means `a` followed by `b`, and continue matching after the `b`.

`a(?=b)` means `a` followed by `b`, and continue matching after the `a`.

So, for `(?=c|f|i)\n` to match, there must be a position that matches both `c` and `\n`, both `f` and `\n`, or by both `i` and `\n`. That's impossible.

Comment: Thanks! That is the gist of what's wrong there. I did not think about it that way. Is there a consuming lookahead assertion so the newline can be part of the output of grep? I want the output string to be "ab\nde\ngh\n" not "abdegh"

Comment: Or better yet make an array out of the matches. Desired array: ``("ab" "de" "gh")``.

Comment: `grep -oP '\w{2}(?=(?:c|f|i)\z)'`